# I want to display all the data entered by user in view_project.html page in django

Tags: python, html, django

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def add_project(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.CreateProject(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # save in db 
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.candidate = request.user 
            instance.save()
            return redirect ('view_project')
    else :
        form = forms.CreateProject()
    return render(request, 'home/add_project.html', {'form': form})

@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def view_project(request):
    return render(request, 'home/view_project.html')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class project(models.Model):
    Name_of_the_organisation_or_Individual_applying = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Name_of_the_Project = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Name_of_the_Principal_Investigator = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    Cover_Letter = models.FileField(upload_to=None, max_length=254)
    Summary_of_Project = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Study_Proposal = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    Any_other_documents_required = models.FileField(upload_to=None, max_length=254)
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is the views.py file where the project is added into the database for a particular user and the HTML file used for this is add_project.html

Comment: Show your models.py

Comment: Is this the model for CreateProject? If yes, you have to use foreign key to associate with the user not a char field

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane I have done that but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display all the project, you have to pass them in your view using Django's context. Also, you need to use the query method on the models which you want to retrieve all of it's data. look into the code below to get a better idea.

```
@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def view_project(request):
    projects = project.objects.all()
    context = {"projects":projects}
    return render(request, 'home/view_project.html', context)
```

Then in your html file, you can then loop through all the "projects" context like this:

```
{% for project in projects %}
<h1>{{project.Name_of_the_organisation_or_Individual_applying}} </h1>
<h1>{{project.Name_of_the_Project}} </h1>
# and so on for all other fields
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to add a query method in models?

Comment: Did you try what I did and did it yield the desired results

Comment: If you need to write queries for models, there are different ways you can go about it. E.g country.objects.all(), this returns all countries in the models. country.objects.filter(name="Nigeria"), this return only the country with field_name of Nigeria. There are so many query method that can be used.

If you need to learn more about it, you can learn it all here, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/

Comment: If this solution has helped you out, you should mark it as an answer, thanks

Comment: I was unable to get the desired results. That’s why I haven’t marked it yet.

Comment: whats it giving you as output, let me know

Comment: The matter wrote inside the h1 tag in for loop is getting printed as it is in HTML file.

Comment: ohh Sorry, i have just edited the codes, I just realized the mistake i made

Answer (score 0):

I understand that in `add_project` view user fills in the form and upons submission gets redirected to `view_project` view, and in `view_project` you want to show list of all projects. For that you need to pass them in context to template, via third parameter, and then iterate over them in the template to render a list or table.

```
@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def view_project(request):
    projects = project.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home/view_project.html', {'projects': projects})
```